# How to open video file saved in hdfs Hadoop using python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

anyone knows how to play/stream video file saved in Hadoop hdfs using python? I tried using the read_file() function from pywebhdfs module, but it prints the bytes instead of playing it. Anyone know python module I can use to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Well... what video player would you like to stream to. I assume you aren't planning on writing your own...

Comment: is there a way I can stream it to like quicktime or videos in ubuntu?

Comment: Remember, unless you have a piece of software that knows exactly how to render those bytes as a video, every file on your computer is just a stream of bytes.

Comment: Probably depends on the format of the video.

Comment: Its mp4 video files..so can i pipe the bytes output to some video player? Do u knw a command to do this in ubuntu??

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but I'll bet there is one.